# How to use bindOnce in recent beta versions of Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the project, we use a large number of static localization keys that do not change as often as, for example, a timer. 
To make the best use of the resources of the user machine, we decided to replace Angular 1.2.19 to version Angular 1.3.beta.18. 
In the beta version added the capability use bindOnce - key display and enhance listening of it in the watcher.

Just code:

```
My cat's name is: {{$ scope.myCatsName}}
```

Code using bindOnce:

```
My cat's name is: {{:: $ scope.myCatsName}}
```

This construction with bindOnce worked to version Angular 1.3.demo.15. After the directive was changed. These changes in the description of the ChangeLog Angular:

> perf(*): more performant interpolation and lazy one-time binding
>   BEAKING CHANGE: Lazy-binding now happens on the scope watcher level.
>
> What this means is that given `parseFn = $parse('::foo')`, bind-once
>   will only kick in when `parseFn` is being watched by a scope (i.e.
>   `scope.$watch(parseFn)`)
>
> Bind-once will have no effect when directily invoking `parseFn` (i.e.
>   `parseFn()`)

[Link to changeLog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/86d55c1ded21a5be6091344493d70c6dc4194e43)

bindOnce was not deleted from Angular'a, but the method of its use has been changed.

I can not deal with how to use that feature in the latest versions of Angular'a.

Who will help to understand it and explain to me the reason of changing the way of using this feature bindOnce in the latest beta versions of AngularJs?

P.S. I am sorry for my eng.

Comment: Dont put `$scope` in the view just `{{::myCatsName}} ` as the doc says

Comment: It doesnt care about "with $scope" or without it. But thank for try!

Comment: No, the most common way of using the bindOnce `::` haven't been affected by the commit you mentioned. You could use it like before. The commit affect only if you use `$parse` service and invoke the parseFn manually.